# React: How can i access a attribute within a <td> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my code, i am trying to pass some data from my onClick() function

```
<TableCell value={i} align="center" onClick={e => this.deleteUser(e)}><DeleteIcon /></TableCell>
```

My table cell is created in a for loop, and it is assigned the value i when it is first created. When the delete user icon is clicked, i want the value i to be passed along as well. in my onClick function, the even is passed along

```
deleteUser(e) {
        console.log(e.currentTarget). 
    }
```

this is my delete user function. When i test the function with console.log(). This is printed

```
<td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-alignCenter" value="0"> ... </td>
```

How can i get value from within the td tag? I cant access it with event.currentTarget.value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getAttribute` property of the currentTarget. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

```js
function handleclick(e) {
var val = e.getAttribute("value");
console.log("test " + val); 
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td value="55" onclick="handleclick(this)">test</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

Since it's React you might want to provide the i value in the onClick directly.

```
<TableCell align="center" onClick={e => this.deleteUser(i)}><DeleteIcon /></TableCell>
```

Comment: It's not javascript event. It is react's....Your answer won't work.

Comment: @Jai here https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-water-qbr8i you'll see it Reacts :) as described. `e.currentTarget` gets the HTMLNodeElement which has the property `getAttribute` allowing for the value attribute to be referenced.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `i` to your `deleteUser` function

```
<TableCell value={i} align="center" onClick={e => this.deleteUser(e, i)}><DeleteIcon /></TableCell>
```

you will get value as a second argument

```
deleteUser(e, value) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget, value); 
}
```

Comment: i cant do that, as i is used in a for loop when rendering the initial component, and will be long gone